# JPA - merge operation, merging a reference VS merging a relationship

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, merge

I've recently been studying entity states and set of operations available in JPA (`persist`, `merge` etc.)

Today I was reading about `merge` operation [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Cascading_Merge)

I think I don't quite understand two sentences regarding merge cascading.

> Calling `merge` on an object will also cascade the `merge` operation across any relationship that is marked as cascade merge. Even if the relationship is not cascade merge, **the reference will still be merged**. If the relationship is cascade merge **the relationship and each related object will be merged**.

Could anyone kindly explain on some example what exactly hides behind the **reference** and what in this context is the difference between **merging a reference** and **merging relationship and related object**?

Comment: Came across this question by reading the linked article and asking myself exactly the same question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the link you are referring to the exact meaning author wanted to convey however you can refer to the definitive explanation from the JPA spec from [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html). The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:

> • If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a
>   pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new
>   managed copy X' of X is created.
>
> • If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is
>   created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
>   instance X'.
>
> • If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will
>   be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will
>   fail).
>
> • If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>   however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by
>   relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with
>   the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.
>
> • For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>   cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged
>   recursively as Y'. For all such Y referenced by X, X' is set to
>   reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as
>   X'.)
>
> • If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity
>   Y, where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then
>   navigation of the same association from X' yields a reference to a
>   managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.

As you can see in the bullet point 4 and 5, the merge cascade operation is recursively applied to each relation.

Comment: Well, maybe that doesn't directly answers my question, but on the other hand (as you say) it may be difficult since it's hard to say what was author's intention. Anyway, thanks for pointing to the specification. Seems like I get it now :)